# C# Отличить одну флешку от другой

Tags: c#, flash-память

Стоит задача засечь подключение определенной флешки к устройству и скопировать туда данные.

Свои варианты:

- Запомнить "**букву**" устройства. При ее появлении работать с ним

  - может произойти такое что другое устройство будет обозначено системой той же буквой
  - или нужное устройство будет обозначено другой
- Запомнить имя **папки** на устройстве. При ее появлении устройства с такой папкой работать с ним

  - *необходимо наличие папки (она может мешать пользователю и он ее может удалить)*
  - *в особых случаях возможны коллизии*
- Записать **файл** на устройство (скрыть если нужно). При ее появлении устройства с таким файлом работать с ним.

  - *те же проблемы что и с папкой*
- Запомнить **объем** устройства. При появлении...

  - *возможны коллизии*

**Есть ли альтернативы данным методам?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно получить серийный номер и сохранить для сравнения:

```
using System.Management;
public static string GetVolumeSerial(string strDriveLetter)
{
    strDriveLetter = strDriveLetter.Trim();
    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strDriveLetter) || strDriveLetter.Length != 1)
            return "";
        ManagementObject disk =
            new ManagementObject("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"" + strDriveLetter + ":\"");
        disk.Get();
        return disk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString();
    }
    catch { }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @Opossum: Помогло? Тогда ставьте галку.